# JPA OneToOne, Foreign Key Getting null on Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have @OneToOne JPA relationship. The values to be saved come from JSP form. I debugged my codes:

```
id = 0
firstName = "john"
firstName = "doe"
security =
   id = 0
   username = "john1"
   password = "pwd"
   employee = null
```

Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @NotBlank(message = "First Name is a required field.")
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank(message = "Last Name is a required field.")
    private String lastName;
    @Valid
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee", optional = false)
    private Security security;
...
}

@Entity
public class Security {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Username is a required field.")
    private String username;
    @NotBlank(message = "Password is a required field.")
    private String password;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
    private Employee employee;
...
}
```

I don't understand why employee_id is getting null:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'employee_id' cannot be null
```

I implement `CommandLineRunner` with the following codes and it is working:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setFirstName("Julez");
employee.setLastName("Jupiter");

Security security = new Security();
security.setUsername("julez");
security.setPassword("pwd");

employee.setSecurity(security);
security.setEmployee(employee);

employeeRepository.save(employee);
```

How does Spring Boot/MVC or Spring Data JPA automatically achieve similar to my `CommnadLineRunner` code? I've searched a lot of tutorials and questions here in SO, but I could only find using `CommandLineRunner` and not using form. Thank you.

Comment: Your `Employee` entity is null while it can't be null? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Pijotrek the employee property on Security entity is null. Maybe that is rge reason why fk employee_id is null and causes error. If you can notice in my CommandLineRunner, I manually set the value of employee via setEmployee method and worked.

Comment: I thought Spring Boot magically does that because in the controllee the employee object immediately passed in to employeeRepository.save() method wothout manual setter. This is how most examples arw done.

Answer (score 0):

Save `Employee`, then save `Security`

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setFirstName("Julez");
employee.setLastName("Jupiter");

employee = employeeRepository.save(employee);

Security security = new Security();
security.setUsername("julez");
security.setPassword("pwd");

security.setEmployee(employee);
securityRepository.save(security);
```

Comment: If you can see above, my code for `CommandLineRunner` don't have `securityRepository.save(security);`. It only has `employeeRepository.save(employee);` but it is working.

Answer (score 0):

> Ensure you set the value of the object's OneToOne, if the OneToOne is part of a bi-directional OneToOne relationship, ensure you set OneToOne in both objects, JPA does not maintain bi-directional relationships for you.

[wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Foreign_key_value_is_null)

E.g. you could define a leading entity that sets both sides:

```
@Entity
public class Security {
    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.employee.setSecurity(this);    
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it now. It should be done on parent - Employee class.

Comment: I found the solution [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/). But I would still like to thank you. Your answer led me closer to the solution.